# VersionOne: Filter Issues by Project

Tags: filtering, versionone

I am quite new using VersionOne and I would like to know if there is an easy way to filter issues by project; I would like not to have to add a tag dedicated to the project name in order to be able to filter them

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the question to my answer.
The filter "by project" is not in the "funnel" area as all the other filters in VersionOne.
In order to filter "by project" the user has to click on the arrow near the project name (in the blue square in the top left) and select the project(s) which want to see in the project tree

[image: project box and project filter arrow]